# How can I check if number has one , or two decimals?

Tags: php, cakephp, if-statement, numbers, conditional-statements

I would like to know how I can check if a number has one or two decimals, and if it only has one decimal , like 12,9 for example, then echo the number with an additional 0, so it looks like 12,90.

```
<?php
$number = '12,9';

if $number //has 2 decimals // {
echo $number; }
else { 
echo $number.'0';
}
endif;
?>
```

I have no clue how to do that properly, any help would be really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: please remember that as far as PHP is concerned (and most other programming languages), the decimal separator character is a dot, not a comma. So your string is no seen by PHP as a decimal. You can format it if you like, but if you want to work with it as a numeric value, you will need to convert it to `12.9`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Unfortunately I cannot change the number before it's inserted into the database. I could format the number to get dot, but it's really for a displaying, so even if not 100% correct, right now that's okay.

Comment: @SDC Most languages now have some offering of an internationalization extension which allows for this. There are a lot of countries in the world that use commas as decimal separators. While the programming languages won't necessarily let you use the comma when creating an integer literal, they should have libraries (such as `NumberFormatter`) which allow them to be parsed out of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that the number is always formatted like you've posted, than you could do:

```
number_format(str_replace(',', '.', '12,9'), 2, ',', '.');
```

Comment: Great, this looks like it solved my problem. This is real handy, thank you very much. The $number always is a number with at leat one decimal. Sometimes it has two. Like 12,9 or 34,99 for example. Your solution seem to be working in both cases (adding 0 for missing 2nd decimal).

Answer (score 4):

If your input is a `.` (dot) separated decimal, you can just use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
number_format('12.9', 2);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`NumberFormatter`](http://php.net/numberformatter) class if you need to support multiple locales or numbers with commas for decimal separators. Such as:

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('de_DE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
echo $formatter->format($formatter->parse('12,9'));
```

**Note**: The use of `NumberFormatter` requires the `intl` extension. It can be added on debian based systems with a simple `sudo apt-get install php5-intl`.

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but `number_format` expect a float so this will always return `12,00` as it will cut off everything after the ','.

Comment: @insertusernamehere That's what I referenced the NumberFormatter class. But I have taken out the indication that `number_format` would have worked for that type of input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. $number is 12,9 and <?php echo number_format($number, 2, ',', '.'); ?> return 12,00 , it replaced 9 by 0. I need to get 12,90. And I didnt vote you down either btw.

Comment: @mlclm Once again, look at my reference to use `NumberFormatter` instead for this case (if you need commas as decimal separators)

Comment: @mlclm I have now included an example of `NumberFormatter`.

Comment: Great thanks Colin. I will check it out also. Looks helpful and can come handy. It's good that some libraries exists for numbers of specific countries, as this solution would be for a european website. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is the number_format function
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: sure it works, if you type cast the input like (float) $number

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP is not strictly typed, you could so something like this:

```
$parts = explode(",", $number);
$num_decimals = strlen($parts[1]);

if ($num_decimals == 2) //has 2 decimals // {
  echo $number; 
} else { 
  echo $number.'0';
}
```

Comment: `strlen` NOT `str_len` , AND `$num_decimals` instead of `$um_decimals`